# Loop is inside footer somehow. Wordpress theme development

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a 1px border assigned to my footer on my wordpress theme, which worked well, but somewhere along the line, that border appeared at the top of my loop.  I'm not sure if I have a missing end div somewhere, or what I did, but it's driving me nuts!

Here is my header.php file.

```
<DOCTYPE html>

<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

    <head>

        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo(charset); ?>">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel|Dosis|Exo|Galada|Muli|Old+Standard+TT|Open+Sans+Condensed:300|Rajdhani|Raleway|Shrikhand|Bad+Script|Cinzel+Decorative|Allan" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <?php wp_head(); ?>

    </head>

        <body <?php body_class(); ?>>

                <!-- Site Header -->
                <header class="site-header">

                    <div class="dropdown">

                        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></button>

                            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">

                                <?php wp_nav_menu (array('theme_location' => 'primary')); ?>

                            </div>

                    </div>

<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
  var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
  if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
  }
}
}
}
</script>


                </header>
                <!-- /Site Header -->
```

Here is my index.php file, which contains the loop.

```
<div class="homepage-banner">

<div class="homepage-banner__bg-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_theme_file_uri('/images/header3.png') ?>);">
</div>

        <div class="homepage-banner__content">

            <div class="headline-large">acetronaut</div>
            <div class="headline-mid">fashion. beauty. lifestyle. adventure</div>

        </div>

        <div class="arrow"><a href="#content" class="arrow-button"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></a>
        </div>

</div>




<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div id="content">

    <?php if (have_posts()) :

        while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="acetronaut-half">

                <div class="acetronaut-post" style="background-image:url(<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) ); ?>);">

                        <div class="acetronaut-post-content">

                            <h2 class="acetrnt-post-category"><?php the_category(); ?></h2>

                            <h2 class="blog-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                            <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(''); ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Continue Reading &raquo;</p>

                        </div>

                </div>

            </div>

                <?php endwhile;

                else :

                    echo '<p>No content Found</p>';

            endif;

    get_footer();

    ?>

</div>
```

And here is my footer.php file.

```
<footer class="site-footer">

    <?php

    $args = array('theme_location' => 'footer')

    ?>

    <nav class="site-nav"><?php wp_nav_menu( $args ); ?></nav>

    <p><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> >> &copy; <?php echo date('Y'); ?></p>

</footer>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>

</html>
```

If anyone can find where the problem might be, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: HI Ace, do you have this somewhere public that you can link to?   Easier to debug the html/css if one can see it online in a browser.    Also do you have more css/stylesheet? the one that does the border you mention?    

If you think you have unmatched 'divs', always a good idea to validate the html (w3c validator). If you testing locally, you can submit the whole local html page to the validator.  Firefox browser view source is also useful at highlighting anomalies (see anything in red).

Comment: I am testing locally, so I do not have a live page for you to look at.  I will try validating it!

Comment: In header.php file after wp_nav_menu why there is one extra closing div , As well as  in index.php after get_footer();

Comment: In header.php, there is a closing div for dropdown, and a closing div for dropdown-content.  Do you see another one?  Not sure, what the index.php one is.  I will take a look.

Comment: @sudharshan nair // Ah, the /div in index.php was for div class content up at the top.  It wasn't showing up, because I hadn't indented it 4 spaces here.

Comment: @AceLong. We can't trace out until we have entire html or CSS.Its better if you post your HTML and CSs somwhere completely, So that we can have a look at that

Comment: @sudharshanNair // I uploaded my local site EXACTLY the same to my live Wordpress.  You can find it at http://www.acetronaut.com.  Although the problem still persists, with the 1px black border of my footer still appearing at the top of my loop, some of the aspects aren't the same for some reason.  The loop, which is contained within a div with an id of content has a max-width of 1200, which works on my local site, but for some reason, on the live version, it is full width.

Comment: @SudharshanNair // Nevermind about the max-width, I just hadn't hard refreshed, and it was still caching an older css file.

Comment: @AceLong, So is your issue resolved ?

Comment: No, my original issue still remains.  The loop is somehow inside the footer, as you can see by the 1px solid border of the footer appearing at the top of the loop, as well as the footer links being off to the side of the loop.

Comment: @AceLong. I think the link you given is not working

Comment: http://www.acetronaut.com ??  I just tried it on my phone, and you're right, it just says new wordpress site coming soon.  SIGH.  WHy is it working on my computer.  It's not my local copy.  It is a live version hosted through bluehost.

Comment: @AceLong. Its a new question again :-). Have you setup DB and changed home_url and site_url?

Comment: It is working on my phone now, I just had to refresh a couple times.  And I am not logged in on my phone, so it should be working for you.

Comment: @AceLong. Nope its still not working